# why use a capital letter for the differential of an integral

Tags: integration, notation

I have seen the notation for an integral of the form

$\int x dF(x)$, my professor told me that this is the same as 
$\int x f(x) dx$ Why introduce a different notations it it has the same  meanings?

Comment: A lot of times $F$ is used as the symbol for an [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to work with derivatives and antiderivates, so we use $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ to know these are related functions.

This is also common in probability where $f(x)$ is generally used to denote the probability density function, whereas $F(x)$ represents the associated cumulative distribution function.

Comment: OP: In case it's not obvious, note that for probability distribution functions, the PDF is the derivative of the CDF where the latter is continuous (and there are ways to handle cases where the CDF is not continuous so that the basic relationship is maintained).

Answer (score 2):

To put @[Bye_World](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137731/bye-world)'s comment into an answer: the "antiderivative" of $f$ is something that $f$ is the derivative of:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dF(x)}{dx} &= f(x) && \text{antiderivative}\\
dF(x) &= f(x)\,dx && \text{"multiplied" by $dx$}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason you're taught $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. Sure, they equate to the same thing, but they compute differently and as a result one may be easier to evaluate than the other. In your specific example, it equates functions like $\int x\ d(\cos x)$ and $\int x\ \sin x\ dx$.

As for the capital versus lowercase, that is a standard notation for "antiderivatives not expressed in integral form". Without that distinction, the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus, not to mention the equation your teacher gave, would be meaningless.